# phonetic symbols in iOS app

Tags: iphone, ios, fonts

is there a way to show phonetic symbols according to API (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Phonetic_Alphabet) in an iOS application?

we thought of adding the symbols with graphics, but I'm hoping for an alternative (e.g. unicode, some library or font...).

has anybody achieved this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This](http://www.phon.ucl.ac.uk/home/wells/ipa-unicode.htm#display) page shows the codes for phonetic symbols in Unicode, in decimal and hexadecimal, and shows you how to insert them.  Best of luck.